# React Router to change route/component without changing browser URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to have an internal route system so that components render, but the main browser route doesn't change?

So if you start with `mysite.com` it renders a list page, you can go into an instance page, but the url remains at `mysite.com`, and so on. If you refresh the page, it will go back to the list page.

Comment: I think you can maintain internal state and based on state value just render the Component you want. Like on the load you will have original state value, there you can render list component. When you move further you just change the state value and render component based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MemoryRouter` instead of the `Router` for this. For examples and documentation see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter

For react-router version 3 you can import `createMemoryHistory` from `history`

```
const memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory(location);
<Router history={memoryHistory} routes={routes} />
```

Version 3 docs: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory

Comment: I'm still using react-router 3. Any option for that version?

Comment: @Kousha by the way, may I recommend migrating to v4? It'll be worth it